# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string d = "4/2/2018 12:00:00 AM";// 2nd April 2018

DateTime startD;
startD = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I get the string recognized as a valid DateTime?

Comment: Have you tried `04/02/2018`? That is the format you specified in `ParseExact`.

Comment: A helpful technique in these kinds of situations is to create a new `DateTime` directly (with 2018,4,2 as parameters) and then `ToString` it with your specified format (`"MM/dd/yyyy"`). What does it output? `Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2018, 4,2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));`

Comment: This is the string I get: 4/2/2018 and not 04/02/2018. So you say it isn't possible to be recognized as a datetime ?

Comment: Simply, `DateTime startD=Convert.ToDateTime(d);`

Comment: @FlorinM Did you try running `Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2018, 4,2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));`? What did it output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patrick Artner noted, your pattern does not match your format.

The correct format is `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"` with

M ... Represents the month as a number from 1 through 12.

d ... Represents the day of the month as a number from 1 through 31

Answer (score 2):

Its called `ParseExact` for a reason. 
Use `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings for the custom date time specifiers and [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Alternatively you could swith to `DateTime.TryParse(...)` Syntax which I would prefere unless you are 100% certain what your input is.

Comment: I tried: DateTime.ParseExact(d, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); Not working, same error

Comment: @FlorinM. my bad - you use `2` and '4'  instead of `02` and '04' - corrected it. It must match Exact.

Answer (score -1):

string d = "4/2/2018 12:00:00 AM";// 2nd April 2018

```
        DateTime startD;
        startD = Convert.ToDateTime(d);
```

Comment: This will act differently if running in Australia, for example.

Comment: wat problem u r facing?

Comment: That this suggested answer doesn't work in Australia?